# Accessibility widget in vanilla js

Tags: javascript

I'm writing an a11y widget with vanilla js, but my code got messy.

Here's my code:

```
class A11yError extends Error {
  constructor(msg) {
    super(msg);
    this.name = "A11yError";
  }
}

class A11y {
  constructor(options) {
    this.color = options?.color || "#17384c";
    this.position = options?.position || "left";

    this.minScale = options?.minScale || -50;
    this.maxScale = options?.maxScale || +50;
    this.minFontSize = options?.minFontSize || -50;
    this.maxFontSize = options?.maxFontSize || +50;

    this.data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("a11y_data")) || {
      scaling: 0,
      readableFont: false,
      fontScaling: 0
    };

    // Checking for types
    if (this.position !== "left" &&
        this.position !== "right") {
      throw new A11yError("Position is not one of the values: left, right");
    }
  }

  updateLocalStorage() {
    localStorage.setItem("a11y_data", JSON.stringify(this.data));
  }

  resetSettings() {
    this.data = {
      scaling: 0,
      readableFont: false,
      fontScaling: 0
    };

    this.updateLocalStorage();
  }

  init() {
    var style = document.createElement("style");
    style.type = "text/css";

    style.textContent = `
      body.a11y-readable-font *:not([class*="fa-"]) {
        font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif !important;
      }

      .a11y-widget {
        font-size: 16px !important;
        bottom: 15px;
        position: fixed;
        border-radius: 15px;
        border: 0;
        z-index: 1111;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 300ms, transform 300ms;
        background: #d9d9d9;
        height: calc(100% - 10px - 20px);
        max-width: 500px;
        width: 100%;
        ${this.position}: 15px;
        display: none;
        flex-direction: column;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        z-index: 1000000000000;
      }

      .a11y-widget * {
        font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif !important;
      }

      .a11y-widget.a11y-open {
          opacity: 1;
          transform: translateY(0);
      }

      section.a11y-body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        position: relative;
        margin: 1rem;
        padding: .5rem 1rem;
        background: #fff;
        overflow-y: auto;
        flex-grow: 1;
      }

      section.a11y-hero {
        padding: 1rem;
        text-align: center;
      }

      h2.a11y-hero-title {
        font-size: 1.2em;
      }

      footer.a11y-footer {
        background-color: ${this.color};
        border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
        width: 100%;
      }

      footer.a11y-footer .a11y-close {
        color: #fff;
        background: #00000045;
        border-bottom-${this.position}-radius: 15px;
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        border: 0;
        font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode, Arial Unicode MS;
      }

      footer.a11y-footer a {
        color: #fff;
        padding: .5rem;
        font-size: 14px;
      }

      .a11y-open-button {
        background-color: ${this.color};
        color: #fff;
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        padding: .5rem;
        position: fixed;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        bottom: 15px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        ${this.position}: 15px;
        z-index: 100000;
      }

      .a11y-actions-box {
        text-align: center;
      }

      .a11y-actions-group {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }

      .a11y-actions-group .a11y-action-box {
        width: calc(100% / 3 - 1%);
        padding: .75rem;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        background: #f5f5f5;
        border-radius: 1rem;
      }

      .a11y-actions-group .a11y-action-box.a11y-action-button {
        border: 2px solid transparent;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 300ms ease;
      }

      .a11y-actions-group .a11y-action-box.a11y-action-button:hover {
        border-color: ${this.color};
      }

      .a11y-actions-group .a11y-action-box.a11y-action-button.a11y-active {
        background: ${this.color};
        color: #fff;
      }

      .a11y-actions-group .a11y-action-box.a11y-action-box-big {
        width: calc(100% * 2 / 3 - 1%);
      }

      .a11y-actions-group .a11y-action-box.a11y-action-box-big .a11y-custom-range {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .a11y-actions-group h3 {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin: 1rem;
      }

      .a11y-action-box-title {
        font-size: 15px;
      }

      .a11y-custom-range {
        display: flex;
      }

      .a11y-custom-range-body {
        flex-grow: 1;
        background: #d9d9d966;
        display: inline-flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .a11y-custom-range-button {
        display: inline-flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        background: ${this.color};

      }

      @media (max-width:576px) {
        .a11y-widget {
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          max-width: none;
          height: 100%;
          border-radius: 0;
        }

        .a11y-open-button {
          bottom: 50%;
          ${this.position}: 0;
          transform: translateY(50%);
          border-radius: 0;
        }

        footer.a11y-footer {
          border-radius: 0;
        }

        footer.a11y-footer .a11y-close {
          border-radius: 0;
        }

        footer.a11y-footer a {
          font-size: 13px;
        }
      }
    `;

    document.body.appendChild(style)

    this.build()

    this.updateLocalStorage();
  }

  build() {
    this.buildOpenButton()

    var container = document.createElement("div");
    container.classList.add("a11y-widget");



    this.buildHeader();

    this.buildHero();

    this.buildBody();

    this.buildFooter();

    container.appendChild(this.header);
    container.appendChild(this.hero);
    container.appendChild(this.body);
    container.appendChild(this.footer);

    document.body.appendChild(container);
  }

  buildOpenButton() {
    var openButton = document.createElement('button');
    openButton.setAttribute("aria-label", "Open accessibility menu")
    openButton.classList.add("a11y-open-button");
    openButton.innerHTML = `<svg x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#fff" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M496.101 385.669l14.227 28.663c3.929 7.915.697 17.516-7.218 21.445l-65.465 32.886c-16.049 7.967-35.556 1.194-43.189-15.055L331.679 320H192c-15.925 0-29.426-11.71-31.679-27.475C126.433 55.308 128.38 70.044 128 64c0-36.358 30.318-65.635 67.052-63.929 33.271 1.545 60.048 28.905 60.925 62.201.868 32.933-23.152 60.423-54.608 65.039l4.67 32.69H336c8.837 0 16 7.163 16 16v32c0 8.837-7.163 16-16 16H215.182l4.572 32H352a32 32 0 0 1 28.962 18.392L438.477 396.8l36.178-18.349c7.915-3.929 17.517-.697 21.446 7.218zM311.358 352h-24.506c-7.788 54.204-54.528 96-110.852 96-61.757 0-112-50.243-112-112 0-41.505 22.694-77.809 56.324-97.156-3.712-25.965-6.844-47.86-9.488-66.333C45.956 198.464 0 261.963 0 336c0 97.047 78.953 176 176 176 71.87 0 133.806-43.308 161.11-105.192L311.358 352z"/></svg>`;

    openButton.addEventListener("click", this.toggle.bind(this));

    document.body.appendChild(openButton);
  }

  buildHeader() {
    var header = document.createElement("header");
    header.classList.add("a11y-header");

    this.header = header;
  }

  buildHero() {
    // hero
    var hero = document.createElement("section");
    hero.classList.add("a11y-hero");

    var heroTitle = document.createElement("h2");
    heroTitle.classList.add("a11y-hero-title");
    heroTitle.textContent = "Accessibility Adjustments";

    hero.appendChild(heroTitle);

    this.hero = hero;
  }

  buildBody() {
    var body = document.createElement("section");
    body.classList.add("a11y-body");

    body.appendChild(this.buildContentAdjustments());

    this.body = body;
  }

  buildFooter() {
    // Footer and all of it's elements
    var footer = document.createElement("footer");
    footer.classList.add("a11y-footer");

    var a11yBy = document.createElement("a");
    a11yBy.classList.add("a11y-by");
    a11yBy.href = "https://www.nonstopgreen.com";
    a11yBy.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    a11yBy.innerText = "Web Accessibility Solution By NonStopGreen";

    var closeButton = document.createElement("button");
    closeButton.classList.add("a11y-close");
    closeButton.innerHTML = "&#10006;"

    footer.appendChild(closeButton);
    footer.appendChild(a11yBy);

    this.accessibilityState = false;

    closeButton.addEventListener("click", this.toggle.bind(this));

    this.footer = footer;
  }

  buildContentAdjustments() {

    var actionsBox = document.createElement("section");
    actionsBox.classList.add("a11y-actions-box");

    var heading = document.createElement("h3");
    heading.textContent = "Content Adjustments";

    var actionsGroup = document.createElement("div");
    actionsGroup.classList.add("a11y-actions-group");

    var that = this;

    var convertPercentageToZoom = (x) => 1 + x * 0.0016;
    var fixPercentage = (value, defaultValue) => ((value === defaultValue) ? "Default" : (value > defaultValue ? "+":"") + value + "%");

    var arrowBottomIcon = `<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#fff" d="M6.34317 7.75732L4.92896 9.17154L12 16.2426L19.0711 9.17157L17.6569 7.75735L12 13.4142L6.34317 7.75732Z"/></svg>`;
    var arrowTopIcon = `<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#fff" d="M17.6569 16.2427L19.0711 14.8285L12.0001 7.75739L4.92896 14.8285L6.34317 16.2427L12.0001 10.5858L17.6569 16.2427Z"/></svg>`;


    var contentScaling = (function() {
      'use strict';

      var actionBox = document.createElement('div');
      actionBox.classList.add("a11y-action-box", "a11y-action-box-big");

      var title = document.createElement('h4');
      title.classList.add("a11y-action-box-title")
      title.textContent = "Content Scaling";

      var customRange = document.createElement('div')
      customRange.classList.add("a11y-custom-range");

      var customRangePlus = document.createElement('button');
      customRangePlus.classList.add("a11y-custom-range-plus", "a11y-custom-range-button");

      var customRangeMinus = document.createElement('button');
      customRangeMinus.classList.add("a11y-custom-range-minus", "a11y-custom-range-button");

      var customRangeBody = document.createElement('div');
      customRangeBody.classList.add("a11y-custom-range-body");
      customRangeBody.innerText = fixPercentage(that.data.scaling, 0);

      customRangePlus.addEventListener("click", scale.bind(that, "in"));
      customRangePlus.addEventListener("touch", scale.bind(that, "in"));

      customRangeMinus.addEventListener("click", scale.bind(that, "out"));
      customRangeMinus.addEventListener("touch", scale.bind(that, "out"));

      function scale(state) {
        if (state === "in" && that.data.scaling < that.maxScale) that.data.scaling += 10;
        else if (state === "out" && that.data.scaling > that.minScale) that.data.scaling -= 10;

        document.body.style.zoom = convertPercentageToZoom(that.data.scaling);

        customRangeBody.textContent = fixPercentage(that.data.scaling, 0);

        that.updateLocalStorage()
      }

      customRangeMinus.innerHTML = arrowBottomIcon;
      customRangePlus.innerHTML = arrowTopIcon;

      customRange.appendChild(customRangeMinus);
      customRange.appendChild(customRangeBody);
      customRange.appendChild(customRangePlus);

      actionBox.appendChild(title);
      actionBox.appendChild(customRange);

      return actionBox;
    }());

    var readableFont = (function() {
      'use strict';
      var actionButton = document.createElement('div');
      actionButton.classList.add("a11y-action-box", "a11y-action-button");

      actionButton.textContent = "Readable Font";

      actionButton.addEventListener("click", readableFont.bind(that));
      actionButton.addEventListener("touch", readableFont.bind(that));

      function readableFont() {
        actionButton.classList.toggle("a11y-active")

        document.body.classList.toggle("a11y-readable-font");

        that.data.readableFont = !that.data.readableFont;

        that.updateLocalStorage();
      }

      if (that.data.readableFont === true) {
        actionButton.classList.toggle("a11y-active")

        document.body.classList.toggle("a11y-readable-font");
      }

      return actionButton;
    }());

    var fontScaling = (function() {
      'use strict';

      var actionBox = document.createElement('div');
      actionBox.classList.add("a11y-action-box", "a11y-action-box-big");

      var title = document.createElement('h4');
      title.classList.add("a11y-action-box-title")
      title.textContent = "Font Scaling";

      var customRange = document.createElement('div')
      customRange.classList.add("a11y-custom-range");

      var customRangePlus = document.createElement('button');
      customRangePlus.classList.add("a11y-custom-range-plus", "a11y-custom-range-button");

      var customRangeMinus = document.createElement('button');
      customRangeMinus.classList.add("a11y-custom-range-minus", "a11y-custom-range-button");

      var customRangeBody = document.createElement('div');
      customRangeBody.classList.add("a11y-custom-range-body");
      customRangeBody.innerText = fixPercentage(that.data.fontScaling, 0);

      customRangePlus.addEventListener("click", scale.bind(that, "in"));
      customRangePlus.addEventListener("touch", scale.bind(that, "in"));

      customRangeMinus.addEventListener("click", scale.bind(that, "out"));
      customRangeMinus.addEventListener("touch", scale.bind(that, "out"));

      function scale(state) {
        if (state === "in" && that.data.fontScaling < that.maxFontSize) that.data.fontScaling += 10;
        else if (state === "out" && that.data.fontScaling > that.minFontSize) that.data.fontScaling -= 10;

        document.body.style.fontSize = 100 + that.data.fontScaling + "%";

        customRangeBody.textContent = fixPercentage(that.data.fontScaling, 0);

        that.updateLocalStorage()
      }

      customRangeMinus.innerHTML = arrowBottomIcon;
      customRangePlus.innerHTML = arrowTopIcon;

      customRange.appendChild(customRangeMinus);
      customRange.appendChild(customRangeBody);
      customRange.appendChild(customRangePlus);

      actionBox.appendChild(title);
      actionBox.appendChild(customRange);

      return actionBox;
    }());

    document.body.style.zoom = convertPercentageToZoom(that.data.scaling);


    actionsBox.appendChild(heading);

    actionsGroup.appendChild(contentScaling);
    actionsGroup.appendChild(readableFont);
    actionsGroup.appendChild(fontScaling);

    actionsBox.appendChild(actionsGroup);

    return actionsBox;
  }

  toggle() {
    var container = document.querySelector('.a11y-widget')


    container.style.display = "flex";

    setTimeout(function () { container.classList.toggle("a11y-open") },0);

    if (this.accessibilityState = !this.accessibilityState) {
    } else {
      setTimeout(function () {
        container.style.display = "none";
      }, 300);
    }
  }
}
```

How do I refactor my code for usability?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not mix css and js code. Move all css code to .css file and just use elements with classes and his own methods.

Good idea is to not use var, let and const is much better.

I also do not like this function expression contentScaling - in OOP this should be just private method in class. Now we have mix of JS and OOP patterns. Maybe scale and readableFont should be separate classes with better names.

I think, that you can split your code in more smaller functions, for example here:

```
    document.body.style.zoom = convertPercentageToZoom(that.data.scaling);


    actionsBox.appendChild(heading);

    actionsGroup.appendChild(contentScaling);
    actionsGroup.appendChild(readableFont);
    actionsGroup.appendChild(fontScaling);

    actionsBox.appendChild(actionsGroup);

    return actionsBox;
```

This fragment of code do multiple things and at the end, returns object. For me much better idea is cut this fragment into smaller functions.

You should not also change explicity styles of elements, like here

```
container.style.display = "flex"; // better idea is change or add class
```

Another thing = you can wrap all your code in IIFE and write 'use strict' statement only once.

```
(function () {
  "use strict";
 
})();
```

Your class A11n is for me way too big and you should slice this class into multiple smaller classes.